# Javascript / Regex replacing text without replacing code/tag attributes etc

Tags: javascript, regex

**EDIT ** THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE AS IT WAS MARKED AS**

**EDIT ** I'm asking if there is a regex solution, that would easily implement into my current code, not a re-work**

I have an object like

```
finalList = {bla: 100, foo: 200, baz: 300}
```

trying to make a script to replace words with their corresponding value from the array on the current website I'm viewing. My issue is that is also replacing matched words inside HTML code like `img` tags etc

```
<div> 
    <p class="baz">bla foo words</p>
    <a href="/img/Hello_World_bla.png">
        <img src="/img/Hello_World_bla.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

if we use the above example as our "current page" I would expect after running the script for it to be:

```
<div> 
    <p class="baz">100 200 words</p>
    <a href="/img/Hello_World_bla.png">
        <img src="/img/Hello_World_bla.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

what im actually getting is:

```
<div> 
    <p class="300">100 200 words</p>
    <a href="/img/Hello_World_100.png">
        <img src="/img/Hello_World_100.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

As you can see, this is causing an issue because its breaking elements in the page.

This is the section of the code im currently using for this which is providing the undesirable results:

```
var a = finalList;

for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    // use a for loop to loop through the array
    // now grab each item:
    var item = a[i];
    // grab the text:
    var text = item.text;
    var frequency = item.frequency;

    var re = new RegExp(text,'gi');        
    replaced = $("body").html().replace(re, frequency);
    $("body").html(replaced);
    console.log(text, " replaced with: ", frequency);
}
```

Comment: Note that what you have is an object, not an array.

Comment: yes that is right, thanks for the correction

Comment: Instead of `$("body").html().replace(` use `$("body").text().replace(`

Comment: If you don't want to use a tree walker, as the marked as duplicate question suggests, you could try `var re = new RegExp('>[^<]*(' + text + ')', 'gi')`. This should only find values inside of text nodes. But, because parsing the DOM is highly not recommended, I'd suggest the tree walker approach.

Comment: im looking for something like this, though that regex is breaking the page, so its getting more than just the inner text, maybe I will look into redoing as tree walker if this method is unreliable